# Python enumerate - what cannot I see?

Tags: python, enumerate

Can anyone explain what is going on here as I am flummoxed

I have a module-wide list variable with elements that have fields - mylist with 'n' entries, each of field1, field2..fieldx

I want to access them in a procedure, so have (with some trace/debug statements)

```
print mylist [1].dataFieldCheckType

for lIndex, lField in enumerate(mylist, start = 1):

    print lField.dataFieldCheckType
```

The first print statement gives the value -4 (which is correct), the second gives a different value, 0, over a simple one-statement step.
To my mind, lField is being created as a new element with default values but I do not know, nor understand, why. Why is the second print statement giving a different value from the first?

What am I doing wrong? Or, probably more pertinently, what am I not understanding?

I have asked this in another forum but no-one has come up with a plausible explanation.

Comment: It took me a while to see what you were asking—at first I thought you were saying 0 was wrong but weren't saying what it was supposed to be. Then after rereading a ton of times I'm guessing you were expecting the second `print` to print -4. I edited your question to clarify this. Please rollback if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

In [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), `start` does not specify the starting index into the iterable. It specifies the starting value of the count. `enumerate()` iterates over the whole iterable, from the first (index 0) to the last element, regardless of the `start` parameter.

The first `print` statement in your loop prints `mylist[0].dataFieldCheckType`, just as it ought to. You're just hoping it would be `mylist[1].dataFieldCheckType`.

If you want to take all elements of the list starting at the second (index 1), just slice it:

```
mylist[1:]
```

And if you really do need the index, too, combine the slice with `enumerate()`:

```
enumerate(mylist[1:], start=1)
```

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!

Comment: One of those quirks of the language that is counter-intuitive to what the design says should happen. Oh I do miss my assembly language programs - you knew what was happening then!

Comment: @ADB Yeah, `start` is a very vague name for that param. I guess the logic is "enumerate these items *using numbers that **start** with*"

Comment: @ADB if you feel your question has been answered on this page, it would be good to accept (mark with green check mark) whichever of our answers helped answer your question best or most.

Answer (score 2):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) yields `(index + start, value)` tuples for every `value` of an iterable. The optional `start` parameter is used as an *offset* value to compute the first element of the generated tuples:

```
>>> a = ['hi', 'stack', 'overflow']
>>> for x in enumerate(a, -4):
...     x
... 
(-4, 'hi') # 0 + (-4)
(-3, 'stack') # 1 + (-4)
(-2, 'overflow') # 2 + (-4)
```

If you want to skip elements of an iterable, but don't need that particular slice in memory (all you want to do is iteration), use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> for x in islice(a, 2, None):
...     x
... 
'overflow'
```

Of course, you could combine the two for great justice.

```
>>> for x in islice(enumerate(a), 0, 2):
...     x
... 
(0, 'hi')
(1, 'stack')
```